# How do I get requestId of FCGI process in Perl using Net::FastCGI?

Tags: perl, fastcgi

I have an application that calls FCGI responder to process some tasks and I need to find whether the FCGI responder receives and returns same reqeust IDs.

The FCGI responder is written in Perl and uses [FCGI module](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/FCGI-0.74/FCGI.PL).

According to [FastCGI specification](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-spec.html#S3.3), I can find the information by looking up FastCGI records.

I found [Net::FastCGI](http://search.cpan.org/~chansen/Net-FastCGI-0.14/lib/Net/FastCGI.pod) library may be suitable for solving this issue, but I'm not sure how to utilize the library.

If my fcgi script looks like below, how can I use Net::FastCGI to dump contents of FastCGI record?

```
use FCGI;

my $count = 0;
my $request = FCGI::Request();

while($request->Accept() >= 0) {
    print("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n", ++$count);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't. There's no sense in using Net::FastCGI when you're already using FCGI. The request ID, if you need it, is available in `$request->{id}` after calling `$request->Accept`. It's not clear what you mean by "receives and returns same request IDs" though.

Comment: I can't find documentation for `$request->{id}` in the `FCGI` manpage. Should it be documented?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that $req->{id} is only used inside Accept subroutine in FCGI (http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/FLORA/FCGI-0.74/FCGI.PL). Won't it create error if I use $request->{id} after $request->Accept because $request is not a hashref? My apology in advance if I'm understanding this incorrectly.

Comment: @Ken no, because `$request` *is* a hashref.

Comment: I'm still getting errors when I print $request->{id} to a log after $request->Accept() is called. My system keeps telling me it's not a hashref..but it's an another story. Thanks for answering my question. I chose yours as best answer since my question was whether I can use Net::FastCGI to dump FCGI record or not.

Comment: @hobbs It's _not_ a hashref, it's a blessed IV ref pointing to a memory address (T_PTROBJ). What you are referring to is the Pure Perl implementation which has never worked correctly and been experimental. It has been [removed](http://git.shadowcat.co.uk/gitweb/gitweb.cgi?p=catagits/fcgi2.git;a=commit;h=08461774b4bdc705d9cebd72862b69e81e3abc29) in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Net::FastCGI](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aFastCGI) if you want to dump FastCGI records. Net::FastCGI is very low level and requires understanding of the FastCGI [protocol](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-spec.html).

Following code shows a simple client that connects to a FastCGI application given as the first argument and outputs string representations of records sent by the application.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket             qw[];
use Net::FastCGI::Constant qw[:type :role];
use Net::FastCGI::IO       qw[read_record write_record write_stream];
use Net::FastCGI::Protocol qw[build_params dump_record build_begin_request_body];

use warnings FATAL => 'Net::FastCGI::IO';
use constant TRUE  => !!1;

my $command = shift @ARGV;

my $socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(Proto => 'tcp', Listen => 5)
  or die qq/Could not create a listener socket: '$!'/;

my $host = $socket->sockhost;
my $port = $socket->sockport;

defined(my $pid = fork())
  or die qq/Could not fork(): '$!'/;

if (!$pid) {
    close STDIN;

    open(STDIN, '+>&', $socket)
      or die qq/Could not dup socket to STDIN: '$!'/;

    exec { $command } $command 
      or die qq/Could not exec '$command': '$!'/;
}

close $socket;
$socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(Proto => 'tcp', PeerHost => $host, PeerPort => $port)
  or die qq/Could not connect to '$host:$port': '$@'/;

write_record($socket, FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST, 1, build_begin_request_body(FCGI_RESPONDER, 0));
write_stream($socket, FCGI_PARAMS, 1, build_params({}), TRUE);
write_stream($socket, FCGI_STDIN, 1, '', TRUE);
while () {
    my ($type, $request_id, $content) = read_record($socket)
      or exit;
    warn dump_record($type, $request_id, $content), "\n";
    last if $type == FCGI_END_REQUEST;
}
```

Example output:

`fcgi-echo.pl` is the example app you gave in your question and `fcgi-dump.pl` is the above code.

```
$ perl fcgi-dump.pl ./fcgi-echo.pl 
{FCGI_STDOUT, 1, "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n1"}
{FCGI_STDOUT, 1, ""}
{FCGI_END_REQUEST, 1, {0, FCGI_REQUEST_COMPLETE}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I think I was trying to use Net::FastCGI inside my FCGI application and couldn't figure out how to implement.. Now I see that I'm supposed to create a client using Net::FastCGI. I'll give it a try and hopefully I can figure it out this time.

For requestId, I end up using slightly modified FCGI.pm, which prints out ($type, $id, $body) in sub read_record to a log. (Thanks to my colleague!)